# How to create a pop up confirmation message with gravity form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, gravity-forms-plugin

Does anyone tried to create a pop up confirmation message in gravity form. Also I would like to prevent the form from hiding after the submission.

Btw, in my Gravity Form confirmation type settings, I choose text as I don't want to redirect to any other page but only wants to display a popup confirmation text.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only way for keeping focus on the page after submit!
input/button `type="submit"` always reset the page!

You have to use `type="button"` for your form submition button instead of `type="submit"`.

Then,use little jquery/javascript code for displaying alert box:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("ID_or_CLASS_of_your_Button").click(function(){
//Your tasks performed when the button is clicked!Use AJAX to get your "input" values!
alert("Input confirmed!");
});
});
```